# How responsive is Guava's ListenableFuture

Tags: java, guava

How does ListenableFuture check whether the result is ready so that the registered listeners can be executed **immediately** or as fast as possible?

Does ListenableFuture busy waiting by calling `isDone()` (I suppose that is a stupid solution)? Or does it have internal tasks to periodically call `get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` with some fine tuned timeout value? If it is waking up periodically to call `get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`, is there a parameter for the user to tune this behavior because I would love my listener to be executed as soon as the result becomes available.

Any doc or soure code references would be appreciated to understand this further.

Comment: https://github.com/google/guava

Comment: @Paul: Thanks for the link but it is hard to see how it is implemented. Do you have specific files/lines to link to for completion checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's instant.

There isn't a separate thread busy waiting.  All instances of `ListenableFuture` returned by Guava or the `ListeningExecutorService` that it provides are subclasses of `AbstractFuture` and call [`set`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractFuture.html#line.743) when they have a result.  `set` itself calls a method called [`complete`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractFuture.html#line.949), which submits the listeners on the `ListenableFuture` to their associated `Executor`.

That said, there's no guarantee that the `Executor` attached to the listener will run the listener job immediately.  That's up to you to make sure of, or if you want it to run synchronously and your listener is fast and you're okay blocking on it, you can use `MoreExecutors.directExecutor()`.

Comment: How does the ListenableFuture get the **result** in the first place for the `set` method then? I am interested to see if that process is instant or not.

Comment: Is the setting result logic controlled by JVM and OS to schedule some sort of callback into the future? And that is out of the ListenableFuture's control?

Comment: No, it isn't.  It's defined in how the `ListenableFuture` gets created.  `set` is part of the _implementation_ of the `ListenableFuture`.

Comment: "How does the ListenableFuture get the result in the first place for the set method then?" You have it backwards: the `set` method is how the ListenableFuture has any result in the first place.

Comment: so for an end user point of view, whether or not ListenableFuture is responsive or not really doesn't depend on it then. It depends soly on how fast the result gets set into the ListenableFuture. Then what process decides when to set the result into ListenableFuture ? Is that process responsive ?

Comment: The process that decides when to set the result into `ListenableFuture` is _your_ code, not Guava's.  If you call `ListeningExecutorService.submit(Callable)`, you're passing in a `Callable` of your own code, and it'll return when your code returns.

Comment: ", and it'll return when your code returns" oh so when my callable decides to return, ListenableFuture internally calls `set` as part of that return. Ah it makes all the sense now. So it is seemless transition from finishing of my callable to initiating listener callbacks. Thanks a lot!